# FFMPEG Concat different video types along with Images and Gifs

Tags: ffmpeg

So I thinking this question has been done to death but none of the solutions seem to work for me exactly.

So TL;DR here's what I'm looking to do.

I have 3 video files all .mp4 at different scales and I would like to concat them all into a single .mp4. Now want to use the concat protocol and I know they need to be all the same scale.

On top of that, I have 3 images (2 Gif's and 1 JPG) I'd like to have a final output video which looks like the following:

- Image 1
- Video 1
- Gif 1
- Video 2
- Gif 2

Could someone help me here and show me a command that I can run that works. Oh and lastly is it possible to keep the audio working from Video 1 and Video 2?

Many thanks!!!

Comment: Adapt example #3 from the duplicate link.

Comment: wow thanks for the fast response! Ok so that worked but the audio is really distorted (where the mp4 has audio) any suggestions?

Comment: @llogan OK removing :sample_rate=48000 fixed the issue. Any idea why setting the sample rate would cause that issue?

Comment: I would have to see your command and the complete log.

Comment: Ok thanks @llogan I'm AFK for the moment so cant grab the log but will revert back.

Last question and sorry for all the back and forth. With the command I'm using from the duplicate link,,, How do I add more videos. 

Like I'm not sure what all the values are in ' [ ]'